# How to apply each item of the list as the corresponding argument for a function in Scheme

Tags: functional-programming, apply, mit-scheme

I have a list (1 2 3) that I need to apply to the function (f a b c).

The first part of the problem was merging two lists to create the list above, now I need to plug in those numbers as arguments. I am not sure how to do this. I was thinking about using apply or map, but I am not confident in how those work or if they would be the right method.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, `apply` should do. Have you tried it? Does it work? Please post the code of your attempt.

Comment: Apply works. Since the list is the result of a function, I had to use a "let" to "hold" the list, and then apply worked.

Comment: You could have done it without let:  `(apply proc (someproc args...))` works if the procedure evaluates to a list.

Comment: I think because the procedure I am dealing with is variadic, I am not able to do that. I tried that and it gave me a cons error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the procedure `apply`:

```scm
(+ 1 2 3) ; ==> 6

(let ((lst '(1 2 3)))
  (apply + lst)) ; ==> 6
```

Apply can also take additional arguments before the list.. eg.

```scm
(let ((lst '(1 2 3)))
  (apply + 2 lst)) ; ==> 8, same as (+ 2 1 2 3)
```

Also know that `+` in Scheme is just a variable. It could have been bound in your `let` as well:

```scm
(let ((lst '(1 2 3))
      (+ (lambda args (apply * args))))
  (apply + 2 lst)) ; ==> 12, same as (* 2 1 2 3)
```

So imagine you want to do multiple operations on the same set of data.. eg. what is the result of applying x,y,an z to this list:

```scm
(let ((lst '(4 3 2))
      (procs (list + - * /)))
  (map (lambda (proc)
         (apply proc lst))
       procs))

; ==> (9 -1 24 2/3), same as (list (apply + lst) (apply - lst) ...)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all of the examples, got it working.